# Can't insert string unicode(1000) to nvarchar2(2000) column in oracle

Tags: oracle, insert

I have problem.Please give me the solution.
When i insert string unicode about 1000 character to nvarchar2(2000) column in oracle.Then problem:
error code: ORA-01704: string literal too long.
i get string data from enviroment server and insert to databsae local.Is there any difference here, encode utf-8,.... ?
Thank for answer

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: How long in bytes is the string you're trying to insert? Use `LENGTHB` to find that.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this,

-Use NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 datatypes to store Unicode characters

-Keep WE8ISO8859P1 as the database character set

-Use AL16UTF16 as the national character set

-https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm#i1007297 .